# Implementation Of Access Token

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, access-token

This question asked before but no one answered it, so IO ask it again
all! I'm new to the Client/Server communication development and I work with C#.I'm wondering what actually a 'AccessToken' is created(I mean the implementation in code) and how to use it in my Server side. Hope there are someones who can tell me how to actually make a access token meaningfully. Another question is, how should I use the access token on both client and server side? The user request for data and operation to the server with access token. How does the server deal with the access token? To make a validation or something else? Can anyone give me a hand? Great thanks